# Error fetching custom buildpack google-chrome heroku

Tags: google-chrome, heroku

I'm receiving the following error:

```
error fetching custom buildpack https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome.tgz
```

I ran `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome` in an attempt to install the google chrome [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome).

How can I install the google chrome buildpack on an existing heroku application?

I'm running the cedar-stack 16